# Not displayed element makes a margin appear

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get rid of the left margin of a bootstrap row cell. It seems to me that an element shows its left margin if there is another element on the left even if this element is not displayed. Read the commentary in the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">

       <div class="span12 visible-tablet">Tablet</div>
        <!-- These two elements never show together. One of them always
             has "display: none." Because of the not displayed element above,
             the left margin of the bottom element appears that screws up the
             layout. If I delete the element above, everything is fine. -->
        <div class="span12 visible-desktop">Desktop</div>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe we could tell you more if you've shown us some CSS?

Comment: He uses `bootstrap.css`, as in Twitter Boostrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way to achieve what you want is to seperate the two layouts (desktop, tablet) with two `<div class="row-fluid">` like the following code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
       <div class="span12 visible-tablet">Tablet</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12 visible-desktop" >Desktop</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The other way would be to explicitly set the margin to zero in the second div like this:

```
<div class="span12 visible-desktop" style="margin: 0;" >Desktop</div>
```

Comment: But make sure you don't use inline styling :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem has nothing to do with the *responsive* part.

boostrap.css line 419 says:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

`:first-child` does not ignore hidden/invisible elements, so there's no way you can do this keeping this markup.

I'd use

```
#some-parent .span12.visible-desktop {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

with possibly a unique parent container (`#some-parent`), like I did [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jEL2k/).